# Send an email through Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have from Account Number and To Account number which exist in the Account History List in SharePoint. I have one more list called User registration where I have user Account number and user email.

I want to send an email to both emails of Account numbers I have selected in the fronted. How to trigger an email to both users (From and To) when new Item added into Account History List?

Answer (score 1):

You can design your flow as the followings:
[image]

[image]

You can customize your email body based on your requirement.